# search into a string and check if the result is in a list with php

Tags: php

Just a simple question about performance and scalability.
I need to recognize the exactly model of an Android phone from its user-agent string and then call a page if the model is in a specific list. So I use "stristr" function and a simple if condition, in the following way:

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if ( stristr($ua, "Nexus S") || stristr($ua, "GT-I9003")  || stristr($ua, "GT-I9000") || stristr($ua, "SGH-T959D") || stristr($ua, "SGH-I897") || stristr($ua, "GT-I9088") || stristr($ua, "GT-I9100")  ) {
        $page = "android_specific.html";
        header('Location: ' . $page);
    }
```

So the question is: is there a more elegant and maybe better (faster) way to make this comparison? I guess with an array and a for cycle?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: a for loop and an array means looping through the whole array until a match is found. the approach you're currently taking is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array might make it simpler to update

```
$ua = "User agent is Nexus S";
$agents = array("Nexus S","GT-I9003");
$page = "default.html";
foreach ($agents as $agent)
{
  if (stripos($ua,$agent)!==FALSE)
  {
    $page = "andriod.html";
    break;
  }
}
echo $page;
```

Comment: Thanks gunnx, nice. Do you think that this solution is faster than mine with huge server requests amount ?

Comment: I'd suggest running tests on this but I think (someone will correct me if not) that strpos is faster than strstr

Comment: I do not know who has considered this response not useful (marking it with a negative score), but it would be helpful and in line with the spirit of this community to know why!

Comment: thanks @gunnx, but what about using an array and a foreach cycle to extract its values? Is it this solution faster then the if cycle, according to your experience? Anyway I've accepted your answer, please vote for my question if you like ;) Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any way of benchmarking HTTP requests to your pages so you can test this?